# How to invoke an MVC action method from a href in an anchor?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm using the markup as follows.

```
@Html.ActionLink(@User.Identity.Name, "LogOut", "Account")
```

Now, I need to add a span inside the anchor because I want to use glyphs from Bootstrap. As far my googlearch went, there's no way to specify it using the helper above. So, I've redesigned it to explicit HTML as follows.

```
<a href="~/Account/LogOut">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
  <span>@Global.LogOut @User.Identity.Name</span>
</a>
```

It works **but** the link isn't always targeting the same address as the first example does. It's because I've got *en/* or *se/* etc. for language first. When routing based on MVC, the language prefix stays in place but it gets lost when specifying the URL explicitly.

How can I specify a call to the specific action method?

Comment: Use `<a href = "@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")"`>....`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "Account")">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>
  <span>@Global.LogOut @User.Identity.Name</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Although it's incorrect I'd upvote it. There's no parameter for the text in the link. Only action and controller.

Comment: Can't take any credit. The compiler and intellisense told me...   :)

Answer (score 1):

On view you can call MVC action with parameters like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("FilterCustomerGrid", "Customer", new { filterName = "CustomerID", filterValue = @Model.ID })">Click Here</a>;
```

On your controller side

```
public ActionResult FilterCustomerGrid(string filterName, string filterValue)
{
 return View("ImportExcel");
}
```